# How to use write to a file using a universal path

Tags: c#, json, path

I am trying to write a json string to a json file thats already made. However I'm trying to figure out what path I would use that would work if someone else downloaded the project and used it. How could I work around this?

I haven't been able to find a solution without using som type of absolute path that starts from my drive.

Answer (score 0):

During debugging/development stage, if you want to update a file in the source code directory, you can use the following approach, and it will work in all environments.

```
// The below code will return the current working directory
// For example:  <ProjectLocation>/bin/Debug/netX.X
var currentWorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); 

// To navigate back to the source code directory, you can use the following logic
#if DEBUG
    currentWorkingDirectory = Directory.GetParent(currentWorkingDirectory ).FullName;
    currentWorkingDirectory = Directory.GetParent(currentWorkingDirectory ).FullName;
    currentWorkingDirectory = Directory.GetParent(currentWorkingDirectory ).FullName;
#endif
```

The above-mentioned code block will ensure that your working directory points to the source code directory, so if you make any changes to the file it will be reflected in the source code directory itself. However, be **cautious** with this approach as you changed your working directory path to your source code directory.

On the other hand, especially during release/deployment, you can manage the JSON file directly in the working directory. In order to do that, you have to copy the JSON file to the output directory.

You can use the below code snippet on your *.csproj file, and it will help to copy the JSON file to the output directory:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="yourfilename.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```